# How to assign environment variables in parallel in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, background-process, parallelism

I'm trying to set several environment variables with the results from command substitution. I want to run the commands in parallel with `&` and `wait`. What I've got currently looks something like

```
export foo=`somecommand bar` &
export fizz=`somecommand baz` &
export rick=`somecommand morty` &
wait
```

But apparently when using `&` variable assignments don't stick. So after the `wait`, all those variables are unassigned.

How can I assign these variables in parallel?

UPDATE: Here's what I ended up using based off the accepted answer

```
declare -a data
declare -a output
declare -a processes

var_names=(
    foo
    fizz
    rick
)

for name in "${var_names[@]}"
do
    processes+=("./get_me_a_value_for $name")
done

index=0
for process in "${processes[@]}"; do
    output+=("$(mktemp)")
    ${process} > ${output[$index]} &
    index=$((index+1))
done
wait

index=0
for out in "${output[@]}"; do
    val="$(<"${out}")"
    rm -f "${out}"

    export ${var_names[index]}="$val"

    index=$((index+1))
done

unset data
unset output
unset processes
```

Comment: What exactly would the benefit of this complication be, assuming it somehow actually worked?

Comment: If `bar`, `baz`, and `morty` take (say) ten seconds each to run, assigning the variables in parallel would take ten seconds, rather than thirty if run in series.

Comment: I've even tried such constructs as `foo=$( ( sleep 3, echo bar ) & )` to work around the problem, but that just makes the assignment not return until the subshell has completed (which in retrospect makes sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some ruminations, I came up with an ugly workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
proc1=$(mktemp)
proc2=$(mktemp)
proc3=$(mktemp)

/path/to/longprocess1 > "$proc1" &
pid1=$!
/path/to/longprocess2 > "$proc2" &
pid2=$!
/path/to/longprocess3 > "$proc3" &
pid3=$!

wait "$pid1" "$pid2" "$pid3"
export var1="<("$proc1")"
export var2="<("$proc2")"
export var3="<("$proc3")"
rm -f "$proc1" "$proc2" "$proc3"
```

As requested in a comment, here is how to make this more extensible for an arbitrarily large list:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a pids
declare -a data
declare -a output
declare -a processes

# Generate the list of processes for demonstrative purposes
processes+=("/path/to/longprocess1")
processes+=("/path/to/longprocess2")
processes+=("/path/to/longprocess3")

index=0
for process in "${processes[@]}"; do
    output+=("$(mktemp")
    $process > ${output[$index]} &
    pids+=("$!")
    index=$((index+1))
done
wait ${pids[@]}
index=0
for process in "${processes[@]}"; do
    data+="$(<"${output[index]}")"
    rm -f "${output[index]}"
    index=$((index+1))
done
export data
```

The resultant output will be in the `data` array.

Comment: I think you mean `export var1=$(<"$proc1")` etc? I don't think you need to save the PID's of the children, doesn't `wait` wait for all of them if none are listed

Comment: I tracked the PIDs and `wait` on them explicitly because it's possible there are other backgrounded tasks we don't need to wait for the completion of.

Comment: That worked with the suggestion from @ilkkachu. To add another constraint, is it possible to make this work for an arbitrary number of variables (such as a list being passed in and iterated over by a for loop)?

Comment: Certainly, I will modify the answer to show that alternative.

Comment: @DopeGhoti awesome. This should be thread safe right? Also, I just had to make one change, `("<${output[index]}")` had to be `$(<"${output[index]}")`.

Comment: It should indeed.  I have updated the answer to incorporate your change.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more jobs than can safely be run in parallel at the same time, you can use parset from GNU Parallel:

```
parset foo,fizz,rick somecommand ::: bar baz morty
export foo
export fizz
export rick
```

See details: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parset.html