# bash - Is it possible to capture the output of several background commands without writing to disk?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script with several pipelines that I would like to parallelize. It currently looks something like this:

```bash
result1=$(pipeline | number | one)
result2=$(pipeline | number | two)
result3=$(pipeline | number | three)

printf 'Result 1: %s\n' "$result1"
printf 'Result 2: %s\n' "$result2"
printf 'Result 3: %s\n' "$result3"
```

I want to do this:

```bash
result1=$(pipeline | number | one) &
result2=$(pipeline | number | two) &
result3=$(pipeline | number | three) &

printf 'Result 1: %s\n' "$result1"
printf 'Result 2: %s\n' "$result2"
printf 'Result 3: %s\n' "$result3"
```

but that doesn't work because the assignments are executed in the subshells.

I could redirect the outputs files on disk:

```bash
pipeline | number | one > result1 &
pipeline | number | two > result2 &
pipeline | number | three > result3 &

wait

printf 'Result 1: %s\n' "$(<result1)"
printf 'Result 2: %s\n' "$(<result2)"
printf 'Result 3: %s\n' "$(<result3)"
```

but I would also like to avoid creating temporary files.

I've also tried various things with `read` and `coproc`, but the problem always seems to be that `read` or `var=$()` will block.

Is there a way to make bash asynchronously capture the output of multiple commands without making any temporary files?

Comment: You could write to `/tmp`, or to any `tmpfs` directory you want to create. `tmpfs` lives in virtual memory but supports all the file operations of disk-based systems. They are cleared at boot so if you want to preserve the content you'll have to disk them

Comment: You could also use named pipes.

Comment: `read` takes a `-t` to set a timeout. You could poll the fd from each coproc until they are all done. This is hacky, your life will probably be easier if you just write to some temp files. `mktemp` makes this easy.

Comment: [`parset`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358045/108618).

Comment: It's unclear what issue you are trying to avoid by not creating temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

Three commands will run. We don't know which will be the straggler.

You said (roughly) that you want this to happen.

```
one    &
two    &
three  &
wait
```

Trouble is, that produces three lines of output,
all jumbled together in random order.

That doesn't sound like a hard problem.
Just tag each output line.

```
( one   | sed -l 's/^/1 /' &
  two   | sed -l 's/^/2 /' &
  three | sed -l 's/^/3 /' &
) |
  sort -nk1 --stable |
  sed 's/^[123] //'
```

Now you have three lines of output to parse,
conveniently arranged in their proper order.
Assign them to variables as you wish.

Comment: You probably want a `wait` inside the subshell after the three background jobs have been kicked off. And the `sort` could easily muddle up the order of the lines from any given process - best remove that

Comment: @ChrisDavies, yeah I was thinking that when I proposed the answer, but a `wait` turns out to be superfluous, since all three `sed` stdout's are connected to `sort`'s stdin, and they all have to close() before sort eventually sees EOF. So the I/O implicitly awaits completion of all children. // Line-buffered `sed`'s plus stable sort ensure that text lines end up where they belong. Here is example behavior: echo 2 y 1 b 1 a 2 x 1 c | fmt -w4 | sort -nk1 --stable

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `parset` (part of GNU Parallel).

```
parset result1,result2,result3 'pipeline | number | {}' ::: one two three
```

`parset` is built on top of GNU Parallel, which has been field tested for years. So you are unlikely to get some nasty surprising race conditions (that only happen once in a while) and unlikely to experience problems if your output contains \n, space, TAB, * or similar.

Example 1:

```
. env_parallel.bash
env_parallel --session
pipeline() { seq 100; }
number() { perl -pe 's/^/Foo: /'; }
one() { grep 1; }
two() { grep 2; }
three() { grep 3; }
env_parset result1,result2,result3 'pipeline | number | {}' ::: one two three
env_parallel --end-session
echo "$result3"
```

Example 2:

```
. env_parallel.bash
pipeline() { seq 100; }
number() { perl -pe 's/^/Foo: /'; }
one() { grep 1; }
two() { grep 2; }
three() { grep 3; }
export -f pipeline number one two three
parset result1,result2,result3 'pipeline | number | {}' ::: one two three
echo "$result3"
```

(GNU Parallel *does* create temporary files, but it tries very hard to clean those up - even in the event of an unexpected crash).